# setting an central widget for a tab page

Tags: c++, qt, tabs, widget, dock

I have created an QTabWidget with Tabs. Now I want to set an CentralWidget for an only TabPage, I have tried this with this code:

```
msgList = new QListWidget(ui->msgTab);
msgList->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
```

But what I get is this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCjuG.png

So how I can set that an "CentralWidget" for the msgTab? And display it in the complete tab and not in the corner.

Regards,
Jan

Answer (score 0):

You should use layouts. For example:

```
msgList = new QListWidget();
QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout();
layout->addWidget(msgList);
ui->msgTab->setLayout(layout);
```

Or you can set layout for the tab in the .ui, then just do:

```
msgList = new QListWidget();
ui->msgTab->layout->addWidget(msgList);
```